# What are the current options for running Mathematica Enterprise on a web service/cloud with many cores?

Tags: parallelization, webservices, cloud-deploy

The answers to similar questions on Mathematica Stack Exchange and Wolfram Community are several years out of date.

I'm doing time-intensive Monte Carlo simulations with Mathematica Enterprise (which comes with 16 core support, with the ability to buy more) and want to speed up the calculations by using more than the 4 cores available on my laptop. Does anyone have experience and advice on this?

Comment: Frankly, I would contact WRI support on this issue. Have you tried that? (As a personal note, as a home user, I must note that my success rate on pulling useful information from Wolfram Research support about licensing has been surprisingly tedious in comparison to reporting bugs, which they tend to confirm and put on their internal databases for later fixing very reliably.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have contacted WRI support on this issue, and am awaiting a response.

Answer (score 3):

As kirma suggested, I asked WRI support:

Q: Can I run Mathematica Enterprise on a virtual machine on AWS, so I can use all of the licensed cores? What are the other available options for running my copy of Mathematica Enterprise on a cloud service, so I can use all of the licensed cores?

A: "Well, not sure.  I’ve asked the question to the people who make these kinds of decisions and expect to hear back soon.  The issue is a License Agreement issue where it states the installation must happen on a machine owned by the individual.  At a minimum, this kind of language needs to be cleaned up before me saying yes with a 100% confidence."

Comment: I must say this reflects my experience on their responses. Actually, over the years, I've received multiple answers of which some are not quite compatible with each other. If I were particularly cynical, I'd think they are creating uncertainty intentionally, in order to sell their own cloud services.

Comment: WRI never answered this question, and I have started to have the same thoughts.